# Detectar qual link foi clicado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando adicionar umas músicas numa *playlist*, porém não consigo saber qual música foi clicada para adicionar.

HTML

```
<div class='album-musicas'>  
  <a href='#' id='add-musica-playlist-link' class='addMusicaPlaylistLink'>
    <input type='hidden' id='id-musica' value='1' name='dados'> 
    <input type='hidden' id='nm-musica' value='Musica 1' name='dados'>   
    <input type='hidden' id='nm-cantor' value='Cantor 1' name='dados'>
    <img src='images/button-add-13.png' title='Adicionar à playlist' > 
  </a>
</div>

<div class='album-musicas'>
  <a href='#' id='add-musica-playlist-link' class='addMusicaPlaylistLink'>
    <input type='hidden' id='id-musica' value='2' name='dados'> 
    <input type='hidden' id='nm-musica' value='Musica 2' name='dados'> 
    <input type='hidden' id='nm-cantor' value='Cantor 2' name='dados'>
    <img src='images/button-add-13.png' title='Adicionar à playlist' > 
  </a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-musica-playlist-link', function () {

    var botoes = document.getElementsByClassName("addMusicaPlaylistLink");

    for(var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) botoes[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){

        var musica_id = e.srcElement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

        alert(musica_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: `e.srcElement` só funciona no IE (e nem sei se ainda funciona nos mais novos). É nesse browser que você está testando?

Comment: Não, estou testando no Firefox

Comment: Então troque `e.srcElement` para `e.target`. Acredito que baste isso para funcionar no FF.

Comment: Agora que reparei que está usando jQuery. Vou postar uma resposta simplificando seu código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como comentei acima, você está usando uma propriedade que só existe no IE (`Event.srcElement`), mas está testando no Firefox. É simples resolver isso, e aproveito para deixar seu código mais no estilo do jQuery, já que você está usando essa biblioteca.

Antes disso, precisa resolver outro problema: você não pode ter vários elementos com o mesmo ID no HTML. Como você já tem uma classe nesses elementos, simplesmente remova os e IDs. Nos campos dentro dos links, troque os IDs por classes:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addMusicaPlaylistLink', function () {
    var input = $(this).find('.id-musica');
    alert(input.val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='album-musicas'>  
  <a href='#' class='addMusicaPlaylistLink'>
    <input type='hidden' class='id-musica' value='1' name='dados'> 
    <input type='hidden' class='nm-musica' value='Musica 1' name='dados'>   
    <input type='hidden' class='nm-cantor' value='Cantor 1' name='dados'>
    <img src='images/button-add-13.png' title='Adicionar à playlist' > 
  </a>
</div>

<div class='album-musicas'>
  <a href='#' class='addMusicaPlaylistLink'>
    <input type='hidden' class='id-musica' value='2' name='dados'> 
    <input type='hidden' class='nm-musica' value='Musica 2' name='dados'> 
    <input type='hidden' class='nm-cantor' value='Cantor 2' name='dados'>
    <img src='images/button-add-13.png' title='Adicionar à playlist' > 
  </a>
</div>
```

Repare como é simples: **o elemento clicado é simplesmente o `this`**. Não precisa nem recorrer ao evento.

Comment: Está dando "UNDEFINED", estou saindo agora, em casa vejo se não fiz nada errado... Vlws

Comment: Você deve ter deixado alguma coisa diferente do meu código, porque testei agora e está funcionando (clique no botão de executar acima para testar)

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Na sua "div" adicione um atributo "data-musicaid"

dentro da função script user $(this).attr('data-musicaid') para pegar o valor

[coloquei um exemplo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/tvodgtkf/)